# Mock `Number.toLocaleString()` so it returns same results in tests independent of user locale

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, craco

We have code in our class that formats a number by transforming for example `1_000_000` to `1 M` and `1_500_000` to `1.5 M`  respectively.

To achieve this we are using the following code:

```
export const shortNumberString = (number: number) => {
  if (!number) {
    return number === 0 ? '0' : '';
  }

  const i = Math.floor(Math.log(number) / Math.log(1000));

  return (
    Number((number / Math.pow(1000, i)).toFixed(1)).toLocaleString() +
    ' ' +
    ['', 'K', 'M', 'B'][i]
  ).trim();
};
```

The code works as expected and does what we want them to do, but we have developers from all over the world so based on the locale of the user this test fails. For example for some users it gets formatted to `1.5 M` and for others to `1,5 M`.

Normally we just ignore these failed tests, but they are super annoying because you always see these tests failing but have to activiely check to ignore them.

We have attempted the following solutions:

- Add `NODE_ICU`

  Some users have recommended to use `NODE_ICU` package, which I added using

  `yarn add -D NODE_ICU`

  Afterwards I have added this to our test script

  `"test": "NODE_ICU_DATA=node_modules/full-icu craco test",`

  However, running `yarn test` does still result in errors. I have also tried to run this via command line but the same error appears.
- Mock `Number().toLocaleString()`

  I have tried to mock `Number.toLocaleString` but without success. I have tried the following methods

  Ignore the return values as I just wanted it to fail with the given input so I'm sure it works with mocking

  1. First:

     ```
       (global as any).Number.toLocaleString = jest.fn(() => ({
         ...(global as any).Number,
         toLocaleString: jest.fn(() => '12.3.2019 13.47.47'),
       }));
     ```

     However, this does not work. It is not mocking anything.
  2. Same applies for this code

     ```
     (global as any).Number.toLocaleString = jest.fn(() => new Date('2019-04-07T10:20:30Z'));
     ```
  3. This:

     ```
       (global as any).Number = jest.fn(() => ({
         toLocaleString: jest.fn(() => '12.3.2019 13.47.47'),
       }));
     ```

     also fails, because of the following error

     > Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLocaleString')
     > TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLocaleString')
  4. This:

     ```
       jest.mock('Number', () => ({
         ...jest.requireActual('Number'),
         // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
         toLocaleString: () => {
           return Promise.resolve('yolo');
         },
       }));
     ```

     does not work as there is no module named `Number` jest can mock. I have not found a way to mock
  5. This:

     ```
     jest
         .spyOn(global.Number, 'toLocaleString')
         .mockImplementation((number: string) => 10);
     ```

     also does not work as it tells me I cannot call the method `spyOn` like `.spyOn(global.Number, 'toLocaleString')`
- Set `env.LL` etc.

  I have also tried to set the locales of env manually

  ```
    const env: any = process.env;
    env.LANG = 'en-GB';
    env.LANGUAGE = 'en-GB';
    env.LC_ALL = 'en-GB';
    env.LC_MESSAGES = 'en-GB';
    const language = env.LANG || env.LANGUAGE || env.LC_ALL || env.LC_MESSAGES;
    console.log(language);
  ```

  in the console.log it returns `en-GB` but the tests are still failing even though `en-GB` should return the correct format

I am out of ideas but cannot believe that it is impossible to mock this. However, everything I find on Google is mostly for Date mocking but not for Number mocking and I cannot apply these suggestions to Number formatting to get them working.

Comment: That's an _instance method_, not a static one - `jest.spyOn(Number.prototype, "toLocaleString")...`.

Answer (score 0):

The test can fail because the output of the function depends on the locale but the output of the test does not. Instead make the test depend on the locale too by:

- returning an `object` (or whatever you prefer) from your formatter
- use Int.NumberFormat within both test and the function

```js
function invariantNumberFormat(n){
    n = +(n ?? '');
    const i = (Math.log10(n) | 0) / 3 | 0;
    return {
        base: parseFloat(n / Math.pow(10, i * 3)),
        post: ['', 'K', 'M', 'B'][i]
    }
}

function localeNumberFormat(nObj, formatter = Intl.NumberFormat()) {
    return formatter.format(nObj.base) + nObj.post
}
```

the `invariantNumberFormat` is locale independent.
then in your test:

```js
const val = invariantNumberFormat(100123);
Expect(localeNumberFormat(val)).toEqual(localeNumberFormat({
    "base": 100.123,
    "post": "K"
}))
```

The `invariantNumberFormat` is similar to your function, just a bit shorter. If you need to handle `BigInt` than do not use parseFloat. But the idea is the same. Configure the `Intl` formatter according to your needs, they provide a lot of options.

Comment: Hi, this would solve it for this specific method, but I don't think it's that future proof as you could have any amount of methods where you are using this and might need to change many methods. That's why I was searching for a way to mock the `Number.toLocaleString` or the locale itself. I mean, it is possible to mock any function, it is possible to mock localization for Date. There has to be a way to also mock the `toLocaleString` of Number or the locale during tests, no?

Comment: toLocaleString has created a lot of issues, that is exactly why Intl was introduced to Node. Instead of coercing and monkey patching toLocaleString, whatever methods you are mentioning, make sure they accept an optional formatter object. I fail to see how not using Intl can be future proof

Comment: I understand, so the main issue is that we're using `toLocaleString` in general and you would get rid of it completely?

Comment: I was not talking about `Intl` not being future proof, more that we would need to adjust any method to have a signature like this. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Ah yes, true, you will need to update the signature, and hence there is a price to pay there. It is up your team to decide which price is higher, the damage of monkey patch or the cost of updating signatures. It is indeed tough. Maybe someone has a better idea, let's wait and see.

Comment: I mean your proposal is backwards compatible so it should't be a big issue :) Thanks for that. I am also not a JS dev, so I didn't know that `Intl` has been created to solve `localeString`. If there are no better approaches until tomorrow, I will try it out and if it works accept your answer.

Comment: One more question, if you want to just override `Number.prototyope.toLocateString`, at the beginning of those tests where the monkey patch is needed, why not do: `const proto = Object.create(Number.prototype); proto.toLocaleString = 'whatever function you need put here'; Number.prototype = proto;` ? NEVERMIND, this is NOT possible because Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Number, 'prototype') returns writable FALSE!!!

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a regular expression for capturing locale-independent groups from the textual representation of the numbers.
Ensure equality by comparing the captured groups with the expected ones.

```js
const 
    number = 1500,
    string = toString(number),
    regex = /(\d*)\D?(\d)?\s*([KMB])?/,
    match = string.match(regex),
    expected = ['1', '5', 'K'];

assert.deepEqual(match.slice(1), expected)
```

The call `match.slice(1)` is required because the first group `match[0]` is, of course, the whole string.
The length of the `expected` arrays must always coincide with the number 3 of groups.

```js
const 
    number = 100,
    string = toString(number),
    regex = /(\d*)\D?(\d)?\s*([KMB])?/,
    match = string.match(regex),
    expected = ['100', undefined, undefined];

assert.deepEqual(match.slice(1), expected)
```